# A method of telling if object supports a method

Tags: ruby, file, scope

I am trying to write some file handling code that opens a file, obtains data about the file, then closes the file.

My first encountered problem is that if I use the

```
File.open(...) do |fd|
   var = fd.size
end
```

method of opening a file which ensures that is closed at the end, all my variables inside are limited to the scope of that block.

One way to solve this is to predefine all variables outside of the block, but that doesn't seem right...

My other solution was to use the `ensure` block to close all handles like so:

```
def test(file)
   return if file == nil || file == ""
   fd = File.open(file, ...)
   var = fd.size
ensure
   fd.close
end
```

But doing this if the file handle does not exist or is not created, perhaps do to logic before it for handling errors, the `ensure` block throws a nil:NilClass exception.

Is there a clean way to handle files that allows me to pull different stats from it (including reading of contents) in a way that I can guarantee the file closes, and I don't have to predefine all my variables to escape the scope of the block? (Bonus points if this works for socket handles as well)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put a conditional on that method call that will fail if fd is nil.

```
ensure
  fd.close if fd
end
```

You can also use :respond_to? if what you really want is to check if that method is supported

```
ensure
  fd.close if fd.respond_to? :close
end
```

If you want to get fancy, Rails has a helper method (that you can borrow) for trying to send a method to an object. http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

you would be able to change your code to

```
ensure
  fd.try(:close)
end
```